# Changing checksum of a binary

Tags: windows, binary, checksum

How to modify checksum of a binary?
Specifically,  I want to edit embedded checksum in a dll/exe.
 
Are there any tools available?

Comment: What sort of binary? It's not clear what you're asking - there are hex editors that will allow you to edit a binary file and change any parts of the data in it to whatever you want. Do you want to actually edit the binary itself so a checksum such as MD5 calculates differently, or do you want to edit an embedded checksum without actually changing the rest of the file? If the latter, what sort of binary is it? Different binary formats will have different checksums in different places.

Comment: I want to edit embedded checksum in a dll/exe .

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think Windows checks at runtime that the DLL checksum matches what it calculates itself, and barfs if it doesn't.

Comment: okay I am debugging a crash dump and one of my modules showing a checksum of 00000000. this is kind of suspicious of having checksum 00000000. If I want to debug the crash I need to put a binary with same checksum.

Answer (score 1):

Windows only requires the checksum to be != 0 for kernel modules, you don't need to set it for usermode modules. If you really want to set the checksum, run EDITBIN /RELEASE yourapp.exe, or call [CheckSumMappedFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679281(VS.85).aspx). See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/PEChecksum.aspx) for an analysis of the checksum algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "hex editor" to modify a dll/exe, but unless you know how to reverse calculate your checksum, its not going to be much help.

Comment: I just want to put embedded checksum of a dll to 00000000, not able to figure it out how can I do it?

Comment: The bottom line is you're going to need more information than you've given us about what type of checksum.

Comment: I have added comments in question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this link gives you the file format of Windows DLLs/Executables:
http://www.openrce.org/reference_library/files/reference/PE%20Format.pdf

You can see there are several possible palces in the headers were checksums can be stored, some of which are optional, so you'd need to parse the image to find out what's in there. There are tools like Python PE parsers (google for options) to help with this.

Once you know which bytes you want to change, pick a hex editor and do it. You can even edit binaries in Visual Studio.

[Edit: But, as I commented above, I think Windows might barf on it if it doesn't match the expected value]